# C++ Source File Inclusion "Unique Mappings"?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the C++11 standard 16.2.5:

> The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences consisting of one or more nondigits or
>   digits (2.11) followed by a period (.) and a single nondigit. The first character shall not be a digit. The
>   implementation may ignore distinctions of alphabetical case.

I don't understand the context or meaning of this at all?

What does it mean "provide unique mappings"? Mappings from what to what?  And unique as opposed to what? And sequences of what?

It seems to be a total non-sequitor from surrounding paragraphs.

Comment: IIUC it's just saying that each file `#include`d can only be mapped to a single physical file. I.e., given `#include <foo.h>` and two files in the include path named `foo.h`, it is guaranteed that only a single file will be chosen in all circumstances.

Comment: @ildjarn: Ok, so what is with the period and single nondigit?  So "foo.h" should map to a unique file, but "foo", "foo.1" and "foo.hh" can go to hell?

Comment: That's my interpretation of the text, but I have no idea what the rationale behind it is – possibly for special support of the C standard library headers on case-sensitive filesystems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a typical case, what you specify in an `#include` directive will be a file name. What this is saying is that it doesn't have to be a file name. The "from what" is the sequence of characters (`h-char-sequence` or `q-char-sequence`) in the directive. This can map to some (more or less arbitrary) source of the same kind of data -- for example, if an implementation wanted to store headers in some sort of database, it might map them to records in the database.

As far as the "to what" part, it's deliberately vague -- a typical implementation uses file names, but it could be almost anything else, as long as including a header produces the correct type of results -- the database record mentioned above would be one possibility, but it's intended to allow things like pre-compiled headers, or even building "knowledge" of the standard headers into the compiler itself, so including a standard header might do nothing more than set a flag in the compiler to tell it be aware of the contents of that header.

Comment: Standard headers are excluded from that, since the paragraph only applies to `n(n|d)*.n` format, including the period and nondigit end characer. I honestly have no clue what that paragraph is useful for.

Comment: @Xeo: How does something like "stdio.h" or "iostream" not qualify as "one or more nondigits or digits followed by a period and a single nondigit. The first character shall not be a digit"?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I don't see a period in "iostream".  Also isn't it "cstdio"

Comment: Actually Annex D.5: "For compatibility with the C standard library and the C Unicode TR, the C++ standard library provides
the 25 C headers".....` "...<stdio.h>..."`

Comment: @user1131467: That probably is technically a defect -- I think the intent is probably that the period and following nondigit be optional.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a non-sequitur, "sequence" refers to the *q-char-sequence* or *h-char-sequence* between the `<` and `>` pair, or `"` pair.

The wording comes (only slightly altered) straight from the C standard, which has this additional wording in 6.4.7:

> The sequences in both forms of header names are mapped in an implementation-defined
>   manner to headers or external source file names as specified in 6.10.2.

The later wording makes a little more sense with that context.

I believe it does mean implementations are only *required* to support include files and headers of that form.  That obviously doesn't mean `#include <vector>` won't work, because the wording doesn't say implementations *shall not* support other forms, and there is other wording requiring that headers behave properly.