# Is #include "filename.hpp" actually an undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, standards, undefined-behavior

The C++20 standard states the following about source file inclusion:

15.3:5 (page 437):

> The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences consisting of one or more nondigits or
> digits (5.10) followed by a period (.) and a single nondigit. The first character shall not be a digit. The
> implementation may ignore distinctions of alphabetical case.

Does this mean that including .hpp files is not guaranteed by the standard to be consistent?

Also does this mean that when a library relies on capitalization only to include the correct header, then it's an UB?

Comment: UB is absolutely not the same as "implementation-defined behavior", so case sensitivity is not UB.

Comment: I understand your point about the case sensitivity, but I don't quite follow what part of this quote would lead to `#include "filename.hpp"` possibly being undefined behavior. Can you expand on your reasoning a little more?

Comment: I wonder if this this means that filenames that differ in characters beyond the first character after the period are not necessarily treated as unique.  e.g.:  "library.hpp" and "library.h" may conflict or refer to the same file.  Your excerpt *does* come from the section _Guarantee that header file names are unique_.  Similarly, "library.h" and "Library.h" may conflict or refer to the same file.

Comment: I think the OP confusion come from the "sequences consisting of one or more nondigits or digits (5.10) followed by a period (.) __and a single nondigit__"

Comment: Also asked on this site: [What's special about C++ header files with single-letter extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702219/whats-special-about-c-header-files-with-single-letter-extensions) and [C++ Source File Inclusion "Unique Mappings"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014593/c-source-file-inclusion-unique-mappings)

Comment: Is that why peoples c++ headers are sometimes `foo.H` so the *a single nondigit* part remains true?